# Добавить лого для exe cmake windows qt5

Tags: c++, qt5, cmake

Пробовал разные методы добавления ico значка, однако результата нет. Значок ICO расположен в корневой папке CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html

Answer (score 0):

Проще через Resource Hacker закинуть туда *.ico файл и переименировать группу в ICON